# Delaunay Triangulation or EMST function

Tags: open-source, scientific-computing, algorithms, geometry

I am looking for stand-alone code to build the Delaunay triangulation of a set of 2D points. (No constraint, Euclidean metric.) In fact I need it to build a Euclidean Minimum Spanning Tree, so that a direct implementation can do as well.

I have two requirements:

- should correctly handle aligned and cocircular points correctly (the coordinates are small integers, 64 bits arithmetic will be exact);
- should be time-efficient, O(N Log N) (such as Fortune's sweepline or Lee & Schachter divide & conquer).

The language is preferably C or C++ but I can translate from others. (I prefer a lightweight solution to a full-fledged package such as CGAL.)

Comment: did you have a look at metis (http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview)?

Comment: @albert: it doesn't address Delaunay/Voronoi, nor even ordinary MST's, does it ?

Comment: Not sure about it. Please mention your requirements regarding Voronoi combination Delaunay/Voronoi i the question.

Comment: @albert: I need an EMST solution, which I am ready to implement myself from a Delaunay triangulation. This is said in the question.